# How did Google implement views, such as ToggleButton

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a custom view, and I want to implement an interface
`public class PokerCardView extends CardView implements Checkable`

So I want to check how Google implements interface Checkable, and I found 
`public abstract class CompoundButton extends Button implements Checkable`

But when I open CompoundButton.class, I didn't see any meaningful code, it seems all methods in this file only do one thing, `throw new RuntimeException("Stub!")`.
And the same to ToggleButton.class

So where can I found the real code to implement Checkable, such as setChecked(), toggle().

```
// CompoundButton.class
public abstract class CompoundButton extends Button implements Checkable {
public CompoundButton(Context context) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super((Context)null, (AttributeSet)null, 0, 0);
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void toggle() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public boolean performClick() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

@ExportedProperty
public boolean isChecked() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setButtonDrawable(int resId) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setButtonDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public Drawable getButtonDrawable() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setButtonTintList(ColorStateList tint) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public ColorStateList getButtonTintList() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void setButtonTintMode(Mode tintMode) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public Mode getButtonTintMode() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public int getCompoundPaddingRight() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void drawableHotspotChanged(float x, float y) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void jumpDrawablesToCurrentState() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void onProvideAutofillStructure(ViewStructure structure, int flags) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void autofill(AutofillValue value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public int getAutofillType() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public AutofillValue getAutofillValue() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
    void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton var1, boolean var2);
}
}
```

Comment: https://source.android.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download sources in SDK manager.

Comment: And that tops them all .